# How to get system login time through java program

Tags: java, spring, operating-system

I am building one application using Spring 4.0 where, I need to know System login and turn off time in my application.

I didn't try anything for this because I really don't know how to do this even it is possible or not.

While we open system is there any file in OS where time is storing automatically, if no is there any other way to solve this.

Please help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean uptime?

Comment: Yes uptime and downtime also. @ScaryWombat

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. Your java application will be running on a machine / server. You can get the current time on the server and also the uptime (time for which the server is running). How would you get the time when you shutdown the server? Your application would already have been killed by that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in windows :

```
#net statistics server
```

The line that start with "Statistics since …" provides the time that the server was up from

in linux use

```
#uptime
```

run that command using process builder in java.